# Android walking app for walking geared around how far you are from your home or car

Tags: android, gps, fitness

I see a lot of apps let you plan walks or track walks as you do them, but I am looking for something different.

I am looking for an app that is more geared towards something like this. Let's say I have 2 hours to take a walk. I set my starting location and that I have 2 hours. After an hour the app would check how far I am from my starting location. Let's say I made some sort of C shape as I walked and am now 30 min from home, it would not bother me. Let's say in another 15 minutes, I have wondered 45 minutes away. At this time it would tell me that I must go home to return on time. It would alert me, and show me directions to return.

I have used MapMyRun, and am now trying Walk with Map My Walk as it seems most popular, but I do not see features for what I am looking for.

I don't mind paying for an app, but I do not want a monthly subscription